# Can one attribute have two foreign keys?

Tags: database, attributes, foreign-keys, relational

Just doing some Relational Database work.
Quick question, can one attribute have two foreign keys?

For example, is this legal:

PERSONAL_RECORDS.Date_of_birth has a foreign key in CASUAL.Date_of_birth as well as a foreign key in MANAGER.Date_of_birth

Basically, can one attribute, have a foreign key from two other attributes?

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 2):

A single column can reference more than one table.

```
create table t1 (
  t1_id integer primary key
);

create table t2 (
  t2_id integer primary key
);

create table t3 (
  t3_id integer primary key,
  foreign key (t3_id) references t1 (t1_id),
  foreign key (t3_id) references t2 (t2_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tricky question actually, i would read: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/design-the-tables-for-a-new-database-RZ101772996.aspx?section=9 for a bit more information on the subject. From what i recall from the schoolbench, it's not possible. But there might be a way to do it?

[Multiple Foreign keys to a single table and single key pointing to more than one table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237403/multiple-foreign-keys-to-a-single-table-and-single-key-pointing-to-more-than-one) also goes into a little detail regarding this.

Good luck though :)